# HTML CSS Gradient - I have try everything

Tags: html, css, gradient

Before any thing thanks for pay attencion to me.

I just want to make a grandient.

So in HTML i have create a div simple as that.

Code:

```css
body {
}

.containerallbody {
  width: 800px;
  height:  300px;
  background-color: #0076b4;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient (top, #0076b4 0%, white 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient (top, #0076b4 0%, white 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient (top, #0076b4 0%, white 100%); /*STANDARD*/
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="containerallbody">

  </div>
</body>
```

I have try Safari, Chrome, Firefox and IE.
I Try also every thing that shows on w3scholls.
And i have seen a lots of videos on youtube talking about this, i dont know what to do more. I just want a simple background cover all the body with a linear grandient from blue to white.

Can anyone save me please?

Comment: I have try also istend using background-image: just background: and nothing

Comment: check the answer posted and let me know if its fine...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an extra space after the `linear-gradient`.

```css
body {
}

.containerallbody {
  width: 800px;
  height:  300px;
  background-color: #0076b4;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0076b4 0%, white 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0076b4 0%, white 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #0076b4 0%, white 100%); /*STANDARD*/
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="containerallbody">

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: YOU are just amazing! I have start HTML not long ago, i dont realize that may hapen. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `linear-gradient(#0076b4, white);`. _Top to Bottom is default_